# Relative pathing syntax involving dot-dot-slash

Tags: ant, relative-path

I saw this statement while looking up relative pathing for ant and was quite bewildered:

`<pathelement location="../../../../../../programs/jdk1.5.0/lib/tools.jar"/>`

I know that `..` refers to going up one directory, so my guess is that the `../../../../../../` portion is referencing up six directories, but I'm at a loss for what purpose it serves.

Comment: Yes. Because one needs to go 6 directories up (in that case, presumably).  However it may be better to use one of the [existing] path properties such as "java.home".

Comment: I think my first hang-up was that if you knew what was up six layers why you wouldn't use an absolute path instead, although I guess it's conceivable that you could have a file system that deep if you were looking into a resource. It just looked really strange at first.

Answer (score 1):

There are some instances where using an absolute path simply does not work.
We have two build server clusters; the old is set up according to one convention where the base directory for all workspaces is:

```
/work/storage/project/build/myid/workspace
```

The new cluster is set up with workspaces in:

```
/builds/myid/workspace
```

If there's a "common directory", in our case:

```
.../builds/tools/
.../build/tools/
```

It is a convenient way to access "tools", knowing it is "up 6, then down the other leg, without knowing the true location.

Of course, I agree with user2864740 that in your example the reference is to a "known" location, which should be accessed via java.home; otherwise, changing your java version can have unpredictable results or involve a lot of search/replace.